# Access the row number by its index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to access the row number with an index value corresponding to that row.

```
mydata = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 75, 'height':1.78},
      {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 22, 'height':1.71}]

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
df = df.set_index('name')
```

Get index value of row number 1

```
index_value = df.index[1]
```

With having that index value, how do I go about returning a row number? In this case, 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df.index.get_loc(index_value)
Out[67]: 1
```

Comment: yep, it's much nicer and more appropriate solution